# How to get Dynamic HTML code by PHP or JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to get contents from a website, but when I use file_get_contents() function, I get the HTML code, but some of them lost, I check the site code, I know some parts generate by Ajax, I don't know how to get them, does someone have any suggestions?
I may get some examples,
Site: http://www.drbattery.com/category/notebook+battery/acer/aspire+series.aspx?p=3
Request: I want to get those laptop model which list on this page, such as "Aspire 1690" etc. I need all of those models.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is helpful to show the code snippet concerning your problem. URL links may break or get changed over time making the question difficult to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Mhm.

In JS you can access the HTML content in a browser by

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML
```

Doing this server-side, you would probably need a headless browser for this.
The tricky part would be detecting, when the content has finished loading and everything is in place. (You wont be able to track AJAX requests by `"window.onload"`.)

Doing it manually, you could add a bookmarklet to your browser, like

```
javascript:alert(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML)
```

You could then select the alert's content by keyboard shortcut (CTRL + A or Command + A), copy it, and hit return (as the dialog's close-button will probably be out of sight).